# tengo que hacer 2 consultas en un get y mostrarlas en un res.json, pero siempre muestra una de las 2, esta es mi function

Tags: nodejs, angular, backend, moongose

en la constante busqueda almaceno la palabra a buscar en los dos models usuarios y avisos, si encuentra
un campo que empieze o tenga la palabra buscada lo mostramos en un res.json.

```
function getTodo(req, res = response, next) {  
    const busqueda = req.params.busqueda;

    const regex = new RegExp(busqueda, 'i');

    Usuario.find({
       nombre: regex
    })

    .exec((err, usuarios) => {
        if (err) return errorHandler(err)
        console.log(usuarios)
     })


     Aviso.find( {
        nombre: regex
     }) 
    
     .exec((err, avisos) => {
         if (err) return errorHandler(err)
         console.log(avisos)
     })

     .then((usuarios, avisos) => {
         res.json({ usuarios, avisos })
     })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás pidiendo dos queries que son respondidas de manera asíncrona con promesas, por tanto tienes que esperar hasta que ambas promesas se "cumplan", por ejemplo con [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all):

```
const promesa1 = Usuario.find({nombre: regex}).exec();
const promesa2 = Aviso.find({nombre: regex}).exec();
Promise.all([promesa1, promesa2]).then(([usuarios, avisos]) => {
  //Aquí tienes el resultado de ambas queries
}
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo, me sirvio,,